# VB.NET SQL limit submission attempts

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net

I have a submission page that I need to limit the number of attempts that a user can try in a specific time period.

There is a stored procedure that is called that checks for certain data in database1 and also logs the IP address and the date/time the form was submitted into database2.

All I need to do is check how many attempts have been logged by that IP address within a 30 minute time period and restrict further submission attempts if that number is over 5.

Here is my VB code:

```
Protected Sub btn_Cont_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_Cont.Click
    Dim StudentIDLast4 As Integer = Val(textSSN.Text)
    Dim StudentIDInst As String = textSID.Text.ToUpper
    Dim DateOfBirth As String = textDOB.Text
    Dim IPaddress As String = Request.UserHostAddress()

    Dim sqlConnection1 As New SqlConnection("Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=tempdb;Integrated Security=True")
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
    Dim returnValue As String
    Dim returnCount As Integer

    cmd.CommandText = "proc_ReverseTransferConsent_Find_Match"
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StudentIDLast4", StudentIDLast4)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StudentIDInst", StudentIDInst)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateOfBirth", DateOfBirth)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IPaddress", IPaddress)

    cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1

    Dim sqlConnection2 As New SqlConnection("Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=tempdb;Integrated Security=True")
    Dim attempts As String
    Dim comm As New SqlCommand("SELECT [Count] = COUNT(*) FROM ReverseTransferConsent_Attempt WHERE IPaddress = @IPaddress AND CreatedDate > DATEADD(MINUTE, -30, GETDATE())")
    Dim ap As New SqlDataAdapter(comm.CommandText, sqlConnection1)
    Dim ds As New DataSet()
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IPaddress", IPaddress)

    If Page.IsValid Then
        sqlConnection2.Open()
        ap.Fill(ds)
        attempts = ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count.ToString()
        sqlConnection2.Close()

        sqlConnection1.Open()
        returnValue = Convert.ToString(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
        sqlConnection1.Close()
        returnCount = returnValue.Length
        If attempts <= 5 Then
            If returnCount > 4 Then
                Response.Redirect("RTAgreement.aspx?rVal=" + returnValue)
            Else
                Label2.Text = StudentIDInst
            End If
        ElseIf attempts > 5 Then
            Label2.Text = "Only 5 submission attempts allowed per 30 minutes"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

It's giving me the error:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Must declare the scalar variable "@IPaddress".

I declared the variable using AddWithValue. Is that not correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you instantiate your `SqlDataAdapter` using command text only (passing the query but not parameters) so it doesn't have the parameter passed:

```
Dim ap As New SqlDataAdapter(comm.CommandText, sqlConnection1)
```

you should use the command instead and instantiate your command passing the connection as well:

```
Dim comm As New SqlCommand("SELECT [Count] = COUNT(*) FROM ReverseTransferConsent_Attempt WHERE IPaddress = @IPaddress AND CreatedDate > DATEADD(MINUTE, -30, GETDATE())", sqlConnection1)
Dim ap As New SqlDataAdapter(comm)
```

Comment: The problem is that if you use `comm.CommandText` you just pass a string, not the full command with parameters. Hence SQL Server doesn't know about the parameter and throws an error that it's not declared.

Comment: That got rid of the error and it's pulling a number! I just set a label to display the data it's pulling though and it never changes past 1.

Answer (score 1):

You might have an instance of SQL Server will be case sensitive. Can you check how IPAddress parameter is defined in `proc_ReverseTransferConsent_Find_Match` stored procedure?

Comment: IP address is stored as VARCHAR (20) in the stored procedure

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference for anyone else who may have a similar issue or might be trying to accomplish the same task that finds this thread.

This is what I had to do to get it to count properly and not return 1 every time:

```
Dim sqlConnection2 As New SqlConnection("Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=tempdb;Integrated Security=True")
    Dim attempts As String = ""
    Dim comm As New SqlCommand("SELECT [Count] = COUNT(*) FROM ReverseTransferConsent_Attempt WHERE IPaddress = @IPaddress AND CreatedDate > DATEADD(MINUTE, -30, GETDATE())", sqlConnection1)
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IPaddress", IPaddress)

    comm.Connection = sqlConnection2

    If Page.IsValid Then

        sqlConnection2.Open()
        attempts = Convert.ToString(comm.ExecuteScalar())
        sqlConnection2.Close()
```